# Regex with counting variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to adjust unmarked chapter numbers in a text without changing unmarked page numbers (so I can later remove them). I intend to use a regex statement including a variable made up of a incrementally increasing chapter number to do this.

The text string is like this:

"Introduction text

1
Chapter 1 title

Chapter 1 text
192 (page number)
Chapter 1 text some more
193

2
Chapter 2 title

Chapter 2 text
194
And so on"

Using the variable chapter_fix = 1 combined with the operator of chapter_fix = chapter_fix =+ 1
I want to take the regex strings `'\n1\n', '\n2\n', '\n3\n'...`up to `'\n365\n'` and convert it to the strings `'\nChapter 1\n', '\nChapter 2\n', '\nChapter 3\n'...`up to `'\nChapter 365\n'` without modifying those random page number that are not in the same number series.

Unfortunately, I am an amateur coder and despite working on this problem for several hours and having some basis in similar regex problems I just really can't figure it out. Frankly I don't even really have any usable code to present as an example but I would really appreciate help in figuring this out to learn this better.

I have included my current, profoundly incorrect, code below. I am just going to make the adjustment manually this time but I'd still like to learn to do it right if anybody can help.

```
###Module imports###
import re

text = '''
Intro Text

SECTION I
Section I Title
118

1
Chapter 1 Title
119
text

121
text

122

2
Chapter 2 Title
text
'''
###Function Definitions###

def chapter_correction (text):
      
    chapter_correction = 1
    pattern = r'\n{}\n'.format(chapter_correction)
    print(pattern)
    text = re.sub(pattern, text, chapter_correction, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    chapter_correction += 1
    return text

text = chapter_correction (text)
print(text)
```

Comment: Does it literally say `Chapter 1`, `Chapter 2` etc.?

Comment: And what you want to be able to do is push the number of the chapters up by one?

Comment: It does not say Chapter. It just says 1, 2, 3, etc. but this text is interspersed with page numbers counting up for 192 and the actual text.

My hope in the end is to use this iterating variable in the regular expression to recognize the series of numbers from the chapters, add the word chapter, and then in the next step cut out all other numbers.